# Using SIMD-equivalent (NEON) for ARM arhitectures

Tags: mono, unity-game-engine, arm, simd, neon

I am thinking about developing my unity3d game using NEON instruction set-oriented calculations. Is this possible in Mono c# .net?

I know that Mono can make use of SIMD for SSE-compatible cpus, but is there a way to do so for ARM cpus using NEON?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. ARM cortexA series has neon compatibility. an option like 
    -mfpu=neon
while building makes use of NEON registers

Comment: have you tried this in unity3d? is the syntax the same as for SSE cpus (i.e. using the Mono SIMD library's types such as Vector3f)? Any documentation regarding this?

Comment: Sorry. I haven't worked on unity3d. So do not have an idea on that.